# Why is 'Subnet calculators' giving me a different host address range

Tags: subnet, cidr

I'm setting up a network for three departments. This is the IP address I'm subneting from: 10.10.15.0

The first department is composed of 275 hosts. And I will need a /23 subnet mask to cover all of them. So through my own calculations this block will be 10.10.15.0 -> 10.10.16.255. Have I understood this correctly? Because when I type my IP-address and subnetmask into a couple of calculators it creates the block from 10.10.14.0 -> 10.10.15.255 instead. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculators are correct, the starting address in a /23 network will always have an even third octet. (And for a /22 it’ll be divisible by 4, for a /21 it’ll be divisible by 8, etc.)

It may help to look at the addresses in binary rather than decimal. In binary, 10.10.15.0 would be written:

```
00001010.00001010.00001111.00000000
```

In a/23, the first 23 bits are the network prefix, and the remaining 9 are the host identifier:

```
00001010.00001010.0000111  1.00000000
|<-  Network prefix   ->|  |<-Host->|
```

Note that the host portion of this address is not all zeroes, so it's not the first address in the block; that would be:

```
00001010.00001010.0000111  0.00000000    = 10.10.14.0
```

Similarly, the last address will have all ones in the host portion:

```
00001010.00001010.0000111  1.11111111    = 10.10.15.255
```

BTW, if you expand 10.10.16.255 out in binary, it looks like this:

```
00001010.00001010.0001000  0.11111111
```

...which shows that it doesn't have the same network prefix, and therefore isn't in the same block.

Comment: Thank you! That explains it all! I have one more question I would hope you could help me with:

If I want to create a network for 3 departments. A=300 hosts, B=50 and C=25. And my starting IP is: 10.10.254.0. How do I go about subneting all of these hosts?

As I see it I only have until 10.10.255.255 of possible adresses right? Will I just have to start it from an earlier address in this case? In that case what is the correct way? To just pick the highest IP that fits them all?

Comment: @Magnarok What is the subnet mask for 10.10.254.0? The starting address isn't enough to tell (it could be /23, /24, /25,...). But it is enough to tell that it's not big enough for those three departments. The biggest that network could be is 10.10.254.0/23 (512 addresses), but if you subnet it the biggest possible subnet would be a /24 (256 addresses, 254 usable), which isn't enough for department A. BTW, I'd consider it a serious mistake to allocate network blocks just big enough for the current demand; you don't want to have to renumber your network just because department expanded a little.

Comment: Forgot to mention subnetmask is /23, my bad! It's an assignment I have at my school, which I find strange. Because it wants me to create subnets for each department, but it also wants me to start from the IP-address 10.10.254.0. In this case I guess my only solution is to change 254 to 252, right?

And here is a stupid question really as I know the answer to it already, but if it goes past 10.10.255.255 it will not start counting from 10.11.0.0 right?

Comment: Yeah, 10.10.254.0/23 only includes up to 10.10.255.255, so I don't see how to do it. Unless it's considered acceptable to split department A between two subnets? If that's ok, you could allocate a /24 *and* a /25 to dept A, and give the other two departments a /26 each.

Comment: The assignment is like this: (maybe I'm misinterpreting it) given IP is 10.10.a.b/c where a's first 4 bits being 1111, rest is up to me to decide for it to fit the three departments.

Comment: @Magnarok That's 10.10.240/20, which has plenty of addresses for those departments. Diagram out the binary, like I did above.

Comment: Thank you! My head is tired, but I went with that one also after I spelled it out. Thanks for confirming it, you have been of great help, much appreciated. Good night! :)

Answer (score 0):

This graphic representation of 10.10.15.0/23 might help.
It shows that the address is a HOST.
10.10.14.0/23 is the network address.
[image]